# How to prompt users for their name and then return it back in scrambled form using INPUT and RANDPERM

Tags: matlab, input

Using MATLAB I  need to write a script that asks the users for their name using `input`. 
Then it returns their name in scrambled fashion using `randperm`.

I have the following to get the user's name:

```
>>name = input('what is your name: ', 's');   
% user types name
% At this point, the variable: name, will contain 
% whatever value the user types (as a string of characters),
```

I don't know how to use `randperm` to return scrambled version of their user name.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: why not look into the documentation? -> http://bit.ly/14E9fG7

Comment: I did and it didn't help me to understand what to do with a text string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
name = input('what is your name: ', 's');
name(randperm(numel(name)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
scrambledname = name(randperm(numel(name)))
```

Here `numel(name)` gives you the number of characters in `name` - let's say it's 10, for example. Then `randperm(10)` gives you a random ordering of the numbers 1 to 10 - perhaps it might be [2 5 7 1 8 3 9 10 4 6].

This is then used to index into `name`. Remember that in MATLAB everything is an array, even strings such as `name`, which is an array of characters. When you apply that random array as an index, it gives you the second character of `name`, followed by the fifth character, followed by the seventh character, etc.